# TouchableOpacity is not detecting instant touch

Tags: javascript, react-native

I used TouchableOpacity to make a custom button component but its opacity works after some delay when I touch the button using expo client app.

The code of my component is following:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const CustomButton = ({ label, btnStyle, textStyle, btnType }) => {

    const checkBtnType = type => {
        if (type === "small") return styles.btnSmall;
        if (type === "medium") return styles.btnMedium;
        if (type === "large") return styles.btnLarge;
    }

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.4}
            style={{ ...styles.btn, ...checkBtnType(btnType), ...btnStyle }}>
            <Text style={{ ...styles.text, ...textStyle }}>{label}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    btn: {
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        borderRadius: 25,
    },
    btnSmall: {
        height: 34,
        width: 140,
    },
    btnMedium: {
        height: 50,
        width: 162,
    },
    btnLarge: {
        height: 50,
        width: 347,
    },
    text: {
        fontSize: 14,
        fontFamily: 'SFPro-Regular',
        fontWeight: "bold",
    }
});

export default CustomButton;
```

I am using my component inside a screen. The for the screen is following:

```
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, View, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import CustomButton from '../components/customButton';
import Heading from '../components/heading';
import Colors from '../constants/Colors';

const SignUp = (props) => {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <StatusBar backgroundColor="#ffffff" barStyle="dark-content" />
            <Heading label="Sign up" style={styles.topHeading} />
            <Heading label="Sign up with" style={styles.subHeading} />
            <CustomButton label="Email" btnType="large" style={{ backgroundColor: Colors.primary }} />
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: "center",
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
    },
    topHeading: {
        fontSize: 24,
        paddingTop: 42,
        paddingBottom: 180,
    },
    subHeading: {
        fontSize: 14,
        alignSelf: "flex-start",
        paddingVertical: 20,
    }
});

export default SignUp;
```

I have also used the same component in another project and did not face any issue.

Answer (score 0):

`TouchableOpacity` wraps its children with `Animated.View`. It seems your styles affected to animated styles. Are inside `{ ...styles.btn, ...checkBtnType(btnType), ...btnStyle }` some opacity props ?

Comment: No, there are no opacity props in any of the style objects. @Batraz Jioty

Comment: ```<TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.4}>
    <View style={{ ...styles.btn, ...checkBtnType(btnType), ...btnStyle }}>
      <Text style={{ ...styles.text, ...textStyle }}>{label}</Text>
    </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>``` - try this, same ?

Comment: yes same delay is happening even when I wrapped the text component inside a View and passed the style object to View as you did in the code. @Batraz Jioty

Comment: Fantastic ) Could you share code where CustomButton is using ?